# What, if any, are the differences between hemiwicking and wicking?

Tags: materials, surface-chemistry

I'm encountering these two terms, but their uses seem to be different, and there's little documentation out there defining the terms.

Here is an example definition I've found of Wicking:

> **Wicking** is the spontaneous flow of a liquid in a porous substrate, driven by capillary forces.$^1$

Here is an example definition I've found of hemiwicking (notice little difference between the one above):

> **Hemiwicking** refers to the spreading of a liquid on a rough hydrophilic surface driven by capillarity.$^2$

Below is a typical depiction showing Wenzel wetting (a), Cassie-Baxter wetting (B), and hemiwicking(c).$^3$ My assumption would be that Wenzel wetting would actually be an example of wicking?

[image: Schematic drawing of (a) Wenzel wetting, (b) Cassie-Baxter wetting and (c) hemi-wicking.]

1. http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/004051759606601008
2. http://fluids.snu.ac.kr/Publication/hemiwicking.pdf
3. http://jss.ecsdl.org/content/3/1/N3095/F3.expansion.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not especially familiar with the detailed differences between the two much beyond the definitions you've posted here, but it seems to me that:

- **Wicking** occurs in the *bulk volume* of a *porous* substrate, not just on the surface; whereas
- **Hemiwicking** occurs strictly *on the surface* of an otherwise *impermeable* substrate

As you note, in both cases the fluid movement ***is*** driven by capillarity, however.

> My assumption would be that Wenzel wetting would actually be an example of wicking?

**I disagree.** All three panels of the figure you've posted look to me as though they are trying to illustrate strictly surface phenomena, and thus **none of them are forms of *wicking***.  The main difference between (a) and (c) is that in (a) the structured surface is wetted *only immediately adjacent* to the liquid drop, whereas in (c) the surface is wetted in an area *beyond* the extent of the drop. **Thus, the Wenzel wetting is neither wicking *nor* hemiwicking.**